# Building a chainlink node - ethereum ChainID doesn't match chainlink config.ChainID

Tags: blockchain

I have an issue while launching my chainlink node with the ethereum client service (infura.io).

I have this warning :

```
Failed to connect to ethereum node wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/ services/head_tracker.go:288 
err=verifyEthereumChainID failed: ethereum ChainID doesn't match chainlink config.ChainID: config 
ID=4, eth RPC ID=42 errVerbose=ethereum ChainID doesn't match chainlink config.ChainID: config ID=4, 
eth RPC ID=42
verifyEthereumChainID failed
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services.(*HeadTracker).subscribeToHead
    /chainlink/core/services/head_tracker.go:552
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services.(*HeadTracker).subscribe
    /chainlink/core/services/head_tracker.go:286
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services.(*HeadTracker).listenForNewHeads
    /chainlink/core/services/head_tracker.go:258
runtime.goexit /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374`
```

and also i have this information :

```
[INFO]  HeadTracker: Head 22528634 is lagging behind, there are 2 more heads in the queue. Your node 
is operating close to its maximum capacity and may start to miss jobs. services/head_tracker.go:90`
```

and finally an error appears :

```
[ERROR] HeadTracker: dropping head 22529006 with hash 
0x0f7cf003aea4411b0f159ddfeae3bee7f5a4141cbfdbc418eb9615d7aa8d09ee because queue is full. WARNING: 
Your node is overloaded and may start missing jobs. logger/default.go:155   
stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf`
```

Can you help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong RPC_URL, or wrong `ETH_CHAIN_ID`.

`ethereum ChainID doesn't match chainlink config.ChainID: config ID=4, eth RPC ID=42`

In your `.env` file, you need to change your `ETH_CHAIN_ID` to match the network you're using from infura.

`ETH_CHAIN_ID=4` is the Rinkeby network, and `ETH_CHAIN_ID=42` is Kovan. So you need to either have to:

- Set this variable `ETH_CHAIN_ID=42`
  Or
- Change your Infura URL to Rinkeby

Up to you.